# the return is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have function including while loop in my function first process is completed but not gone again in click event

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button.expandcollapse', function() {
      // var currenttrid = $("tr.selected").attr("data-id");
      var parentid = $(".selected").data("id");
      var parrentid = (parentid) - 1;
      var rowclick = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id'));
      var currentid = rowclick + 1;

      if ($("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child button").hasClass("expandcollapse")) {
        var parentleft = $("tr[data-id='" + rowclick + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");
        while (true) {
          var chiledtrleft = $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");

          if (chiledtrleft <= parentleft) {
            break;
          }

          $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']").hide();
          currentid = currentid + 1;
        }
        $("span", this).text
      } else {
        var parentleft = $("tr[data-id='" + rowclick + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");
        while (true) {
          var chiledtrleft = $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");

          if (chiledtrleft <= parentleft) {
            break;
          }

          $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']").show();
          currentid = currentid + 1;

        }
        $("button").removeClass("expandcollapse");
        $("span", this).text("-");
      }
```

i want again it comes to click event 
now the else condition is continuously working but i want go to the click event after one step completd

Comment: ok now the only one cycle is completed  i want to again done this function on click

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is right? There are syntax error , solve it first.

Comment: Is it throwing any error... also use $(document).on("click" ... instead of $('body').on("click"...

Comment: there is no syntax error

Comment: Why used `$('body').on` ? try `div` or `span` .. body is document cannot use events

Comment: @KingRider i use span but its not good one

Answer (score 1):

In the end of the function You are doing

```
 $("button").removeClass("expandcollapse");
```

So since there is no button with class `expandcollapse`  . It does not get triggered for second time

Checkout this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9dubj0sp/3/) .  Your code goes something like this , and dont work on second click.

So better plan a logic first before implementing.

You can use this selector to make it work (*only and only if you are not adding the button dynamically*)

```
$("button.expandcollapse").click(function(){
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9dubj0sp/2/)

if dynamic then use your selector with this change for your second last line of code

```
$(this).removeClass("expandcollapse");
```

**Suggestion :** *Better Use different class for .removeClass() at last .  Why do you want to remove the same class with which you are triggering the event. Please use some other class for other functionalities in click function.*

Comment: its working in demo but its not taken in my code ,why? please give me any other suggestion

Comment: @aswathy : are you adding the button dynamic ?

Comment: ya its dynamic added button

Comment: So this code  `$("button.expandcollapse").click(function(){` wont work for you .. right ?

Comment: Read the above suggestion which I wrote in the answer

Comment: if (CurrentTrLeftValue > ParrentTrLeftValue) {
                if (!$("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child button").hasClass("expandcollapse")) {
                    var OriginalContent = $("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").text();

                    $("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html("<button class='expandcollapse'><span>-</span></button>" + OriginalContent + "")

                }
            } this code is i used for adding button .thats why i remove the class after complete one cycle

Comment: ok instead of `$("button").removeClass("expandcollapse");` in second last line ,, write `$(this).removeClass("expandcollapse");` and try , I Think It should work

Comment: but its not change in result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118907/discussion-between-yo-yo-and-aswathy).